# How to filter tweets for bots and influential account or account of interest using twitter v2 api

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter v2 apis for getting the count and tweets. I am trying to fetch tweets based on some hashtag. I want to filter the tweets on some criteria before fetching them so that I can save the allowed quota. The documentation says that I can use followers_count or listed_count or filter the bots using -bio:bot -bio_name:bot -bio_location:bot -bio:TwitterBot -bio_name:TwitterBot -bio_location:TwitterBot but the api response for these filters is invalid operator.

How can I use these operators in v2 api to filter the tweets?

POST EDITED:
so my request where I use followers_count is like this

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/all?query=(%23bitcoin OR %23BTC) lang:en -is:retweet -is:reply -is:quote -is:nullcast followers_count:5000&start_time=2022-03-01T00:00:00Z&granularity=day
```

The response is

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "parameters": {
            "query": [
                "(#bitcoin OR #BTC) lang:en -is:retweet -is:reply -is:quote -is:nullcast followers_count:5000"
            ]
        },
        "message": "There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'followers_count'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product. (at position 73)"
    }
],
"title": "Invalid Request",
"detail": "One or more parameters to your request was invalid.",
"type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"
```

}

I get similar response for using bot query like -bio:bot -bio_name:bot -bio_location:bot -bio:TwitterBot -bio_name:TwitterBot -bio_location:TwitterBot or listed_count.
If I remove these operators, the api works fine.

Comment: What is your exact request, and what is the exact response?

Comment: I have edited the post with the request and response details.